# Incomplete mkdir and copyFile if power lost

Tags: c++, windows

I have an application that creates a directory and copy a file to it. This is working fine, normally. But if the window shuts down correctly and the power is lost, the files will not always be available or complete.

My OS is Windows Embedded POSReady7 (Version 6.1 Build 7601: Service Pack 1) and on the hard disk is "write caching" option disabled. I have a C++ Application. I used also _flushall but it doesn't help.

I have written a test application where I can see the problem. I start the application, wait ten seconds after the output is completed and then unplug the power. The files are not available after restart.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <direct.h>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string csPathName("D:\\temp\\FileCopyTest\\");
    int mkRetValue = _mkdir( csPathName.c_str() );
    cout << "Create directory " << csPathName.c_str() << " with return value " << mkRetValue << endl;
    BOOL copyRetValue = CopyFileEx( _T("D:\\temp\\test.txt"), _T("D:\\temp\\FileCopyTest\\test.txt"), nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING );
    cout << "Copy file, return value " << copyRetValue << endl;
    int flushRetValue = _flushall();
    cout << "flush files: " << flushRetValue << endl;
    char c;
    cin >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If Windows shuts down *correctly* the files should be there. If you just pull the plug, all bets are off. Many disk controllers have an internal cache which isn't flushed by the OS.

Comment: Perhaps you want to invest in a UPS. When you suddenly power off a device that is in the middle of doing something, why would you expect it to be able to complete what it was doing?

Comment: Since you aren't writing any file there's no file buffers to flush (which is what `_flushall` does). There's no way to _reliably_ do what you want with the APIs you use, so you should consider alternative designs.

Comment: The time should be enough to copy the file. If I look after 1 sec. with the explorer to the folder, it exist and I can open the file, but after 10 sec. and not doing anything, it is not finished with saving the file to the disc completely. So I think it should not a time issue. I look to anything which work like _flushall and tell the OS to save the file immediately and for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting copy within the scope?

```
{
CopyFileEx( _T("D:\\temp\\test.txt"), _T("D:\\temp\\FileCopyTest\\test.txt"), nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING );
}
```

Comment: This cannot _possibly_ help.